# fortran プログラムが gfortran で動きません

Tags: fortran

以下がエラーメッセージです．どこがおかしいか教えてください,よろしくお願いします．

```
E:\gfortran>echo off
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1083]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

E:\gfortran> gfortran PSBaseline.f90
gfortran: error: PSBaseline.f90: No such file or directory

E:\gfortran> gfortran PSSBaseline.f90
PSSBaseline.f90:68:132:

       REAL(8)               :: TradeGood,TradeGoodSec, TradeObj,TradeObjSec,MintObj,MintObjBuyer,MintObjSeller,MintGain,MintGainBuyer,MintGainSeller, DV_B, DV_S, BuyerGain
                                                                                                                                    1
Error: Line truncated at (1) [-Werror=line-truncation]
PSSBaseline.f90:122:4:

 USE Variables
    1
Fatal Error: Can't open module file 'variables.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory
f951.exe: some warnings being treated as errors
compilation terminated.

E:\gfortran>
```

Comment: 念のため、プログラムのソースコードも質問に追記してみてください。

Answer (score 0):

エラーメッセージに書かれている通り、そのままだと思います。

Fortran90 以降の有効範囲である 132桁を超えて変数名が並べられているのでエラーが出ています。

-Werror=line-truncation　このオプションを外しておけば、規格からは外れますが、コンパイラの独自拡張によって１行の有効文字数が増えるのでウォーニングにとどまるでしょう。

Comment: 有難うございます．プロですね